# Using arrays to name image files in a java applet

Tags: java, arrays, applet, naming-conventions

I have lately been wanting to construct a solitaire or black jack game using java. When I started to code I ran into a problem about efficiently importing all the image filles for the cards. I immediately looked it up but I did not get any answers. Wy question is why cant you name images like this:

```
for (int num = 0; num1 < 40; num++ ){
    Image names[num] = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "c" + (num +1) + ".gif" );
}
```

If you find any other problems please let me know. Thank you in advance.
this is the full code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CardsJavaProgram extends Applet {
public void init(){
    String names [ ] = { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10"};
    for (int num = 0; num1 < 40; num++ ){
        Image names[num] = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "c" + (num +1) + ".gif" );
    }
}
public void paint( Graphics screen ){

    int x = 10;
    for (int num5 = 0; num5 < 5; num5++ ){
        screen.drawImage( names[ (int) (Math.random () * 39)], x, 10, 100, 100, this );
        x = x + 100;
    }
}
}
```

P.S. I know that the kings queens and jacks are not being imported.

Comment: The string array and image array have the same name `names`

Answer (score 2):

First you have to declare the array (at class level to make it available to multiple methods):

```
public class CardsJavaProgram extends Applet { 
    private Image[] images = new Image[40];
```

You also should change the varibable name (e.g. `images`), since you have other variable with the same name.

Then you can fill in the array:

```
for (int num = 0; num1 < 40; num++ ){   
    images[num] = //...
```